# i have two serviceworkers that I can not stop and they both keep starting and a third keeps popping back up

Tags: service-worker

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWUGi.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFQXB.png)

I forgot to take a screen shot of the third. I have someone running things through the background of my laptop and phone
I've done everything in my knowledge to stop or click this person out but she got into coding I guess. I have something silent running in the background. this is the first thing that I noticed that I can't kick off. if someone can help that know what should be in turning off or blocking so I can get this person away from piggybacking off my data.